# Разбор предложения по частям речи

Tags: части-речи

"Рассматривая народ как существо духовного порядка, мы можем назвать язык, на котором он говорит, его душой, и тогда история этого языка будет значительнее, чем даже история политических изменений этого народа с которыми, однако, история его тесно связан. История русского языка, быть может, раскроет перед вами характер народа, говорящего на нем."

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то предложение разбирают по членам предложения и говорят, какой частью речи выражен данный член предл.

Рассматривая народ как существо духовного порядка, мы можем назвать язык, на котором он говорит, его душой, и тогда история этого языка будет значительнее, чем даже история политических изменений этого народа, с которыми, однако, история его тесно связанА. - предл.повеств., невоскл.,сложное с сочинением и подчинением, состоит из 4 простых: 1-Рассматривая народ как существо духовного порядка, мы можем назвать язык его душой-главное, простое двусоставное, полное, осложнённое обособленным обстоятельством, выраженным деепричастным оборотом(Рассматривая-дееприч., народ-сущ.,как-союз, существо-сущ., духовного-прилаг.,порядка-сущ.);мы-подлежащее,выраж. личным местоимением; можем назвать душой-сказуемое сост. именное, сост. из вспомогат. глаголов можем назвать и имени сущ. душой;язык-дополнение, выраж. сущ.,его- определение, выраж. притяж. местоимением.

И так все предложения. Никаких трудностей здесь нет, всё элементарно. Тренируйтесь сами.